# Python: 'list' object has no attribute 'rfind' error when trying to create a directory

Tags: python, directory, filepath

So essentially my code makes a list of directory paths. These directory paths are made from information I have in a csv file. Each element in the list is a string.

Then I call a method that takes in this string that has the directory path and makes this directory if it does not exist:

```
def directorymaker(dirpath):
    directory = os.path.dirname(dirpath)
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
```

However I get an error 'list' object has no attribute 'rfind'

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

`os.path.dirname` accepts a string representing a file path, and returns the directory part of that path.

Evidently, in your code, `dirpath` is a list. If you want to call `os.path.dirname(dirpath)`, then `dirpath` needs to be a string.

Comment: Okay so do I call it like directorymaker(str(samplepaths[i])) (I am calling it in a loop)

Comment: No it doesn't, should it?

Comment: You only posted the code for the `directorymaker` function in your question, so I don't know what `samplepaths` is and how you're using it. Try posting a [mcve].

Comment: I ended up having a dumb syntax error that I now fixed. The code works, however the directory let's just say we have a directory path like this: /greatgrandparent/grandparent/parent/child. The directory gets made to the parent level, but the child directories are not made.

Comment: If you have another question, you should probably post it in a new question along with a [mcve]. There is not enough information in your comment for me to help you.